# Synchronized variable don't work for Remote Runspace

Tags: c#, powershell, runspace

code below will demonstrate usage of the Synchronized variable for Runspaces. You can use any ip/hostname for $ComputerName as long it's accessible, Powershell remoting is verified by Enter-PSSession and also you added credential to Windows Credential Manager for $ComputerName as host.

```
Get-Runspace | ? Id -NE 1 | % { $_.close() ; $_.dispose() }
$Runspace = $powerShell = $connectionInfo = $handle = $hash = $null 
$ComputerName = '192.168.0.3'

$hash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$hash.One = 1

Write-host ('Value of $Hash.One before background runspace is {0}' -f $hash.one) -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
$Uri = New-Object System.Uri("http://$($ComputerName):5985/wsman")
$connectionInfo = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.WSManConnectionInfo -ArgumentList $Uri
$connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.AuthenticationMechanism]::Negotiate
$connectionInfo.OpenTimeout = 3000

$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($connectionInfo) # don't work
#$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace() # works

$runspace.Open()
$runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Hash',$hash)

$powershell = [powershell]::Create()
$powershell.Runspace = $runspace

$powershell.AddScript({
    $hash.one++
}) | Out-Null #The Out-Null at the end is used to prevent the output of the object that occurs.

$handle = $powershell.BeginInvoke()
While (-Not $handle.IsCompleted) {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

$powershell.EndInvoke($handle)
$runspace.Close()
$powershell.Dispose()

Write-host ('Value of $Hash.One after background runspace is {0}' -f $hash.one) -ForegroundColor Green -BackgroundColor Black
```

As soon as I replace:

```
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
```

with

```
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace($connectionInfo)
```

(because I want to execute code at the remote computer), the synchronized variable $hash is not updated. Anyone know what I missing? This feature is really important and useful and I need it to make it work for remote runspaces.

Comment: Object need to be serialized and deserialized to be passed to remote runspace, so that in remote runspace you have a copy of object and modifying that copy does not affect original object. It have nothing to do with being `Synchronized` or not.

Comment: @PetSerAl Right, do you have any idea how to achieve such serialization and deserialization?

Comment: What you want to achieve? Do you really want to have shared resource, which kept synchronized between multiple computers?

Comment: @PetSerAl I need a way to: 1. From the server A, run several remote runspaces, scriptblock will do some job and the errors will be stored inside [hashtable]$Variable as a computername = errors pairs 2. Send this data to the server A (for eg to another [Array]$variable), after all runspaces are finished, export it to the file Any ideas?